# Angular: error on cdk overlay when used with *ngIf

Tags: angular, overlay, angular-directive

I try to add a contextual menu to a button, I implemented the very simple example from the angular material documentation and it works well:

my-component.html

```
<button 
    type="button" cdkOverlayOrigin #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin"
    (click)="isOpen = !isOpen">
    Menu 
</button>

<ng-template
  cdkConnectedOverlay
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen">
  <ul class="example-list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</ng-template>
```

This works very well but then I have a more complex button: actually, the trigger button is displayed or not with the `*ngIf` directive.

```
<button *ngIf="accessMenu"
    type="button" cdkOverlayOrigin #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin"
    (click)="isOpen = !isOpen">
    Menu
</button>
```

When I add this directive, I have an error at compilation:

```
Property 'trigger' does not exist on type 'myComponent'. Line 79 [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger"
```

I tried to set the directive out of the button by wrapping the button by an ng-container and adding the directive to the ng-container but it's the same.

Do you know why adding this structural directive make my compilation fail? And how should I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simply to wrap the trigger button WITH the ng-template of the overlay in the ng-container, and not the ng-template alone:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="accessMenu">

  <button mat-mini-fab
    type="button" cdkOverlayOrigin #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin"
    (click)="isOpen = !isOpen">
    Menu
  </button>

  <ng-template
    cdkConnectedOverlay
    [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger"
    [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen">
    <ul class="example-list">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </ng-template>

</ng-container>
```